# Get user's profile data after auth with SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth

Tags: zend-framework2, user-profile, hybridauth

I have a ZF2 project and I'm using SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth (https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) to enable social authentication.

The auth flow is ok. I've already got the user to be authenticated using his or her social login (for example, Facebook).

Now I need to know how can I get access to user's profile data from my Controllers an Views. I suspect that it must be using HybridAuth module (that is also loaded), but I couldn't find out how.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the possible approaches to get access to that data at the time the user signs up:

You could attach an event listener to the [`registerViaProvider` event](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/blob/master/src/ScnSocialAuth/Authentication/Adapter/HybridAuth.php#L533), which receives the HybridAuth adapter as a parameter.  The simplest way to achieve this would be to attach it during your module's `onBootstrap`, something like this:

```
$sem = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sem->attach('ScnSocialAuth\Authentication\Adapter\HybridAuth', 'registerViaProvider', function($event) {
    $provider = $event->getParam('provider');
    // $provider is the HybridAuth provider the user authenticated
});
```

Then extract the user's profile data and store it somewhere.

Another possibility is: ScnSocialAuth's HybridAuth adapter (`ScnSocialAuth\Authentication\Adapter\HybridAuth`) implements a [`<service>ToLocalUser`](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/blob/master/src/ScnSocialAuth/Authentication/Adapter/HybridAuth.php#L327) method for each supported service, so you could override ZfcUser's entity to add some extra fields then extend the HybridAuth adapter class to override each of those methods and populate your ZfcUser entity with the necessary profile data.

Comment: Hi Adam Lundrigan. Thanks for you answer. As soon as I try both suggestions I give a feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed by Adam Lundrigan are OK. But there is another one that I would like to let registered here.

The following piece of code can be called from a controller's action:

```
    $hybridAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('HybridAuth');
// if the user is connected, authenticate will return an instance of the provider adapter
$adapter = $hybridAuth->authenticate('facebook');
if (!$adapter->isUserConnected()) {
    // do something sensible for a logged out user...
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('some-logged-out-route');
}
$userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
```

I would like to thank Nicholas Calugar for showing me this alternative solution.